# Override attempt auth method in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I'm having a big problem with Auth:attempt method in laravel 5.2, and I wish I can override it. 
I have the class users, by default, but doesn't containt the attribut 'email', this last one is containing in an other class user_contacts, with relation one to one with users.
Can I override this function? because by default, it takes 'email', which is not in users in my case
I tried to make that in the model, but not working:

```
lass User extends Authenticatable
```

{

```
public function __construct(array $attr = array())
{
    parent::__construct($attr);

    $this->email = $this->user_contacts()->email;
}

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function user_contacts()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\UserContact', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

}

It just says that the email field is not defined.
Any suggestion plz?
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

Manually authenticating user https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users

You can use any field you want, 'email' field is just the default.

Something like this will work perfectly fine:

```
if(Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])){
  return redirect()->intended('admin');
}
```